# Error on rename of a column during a migration in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration

I am trying to run a migration in rails to change the name of a column but I am getting this error:

```
Mysql::Error: Error on rename of './databasename/#sql-478_17b' to './databasename/zz_portal_users' (errno: 150): ALTER TABLE `zz_portal_users` CHANGE `user_id` `zz_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
```

Here is the migration I am trying to run:

```
class RenameUsersIdToZzUsersIdInZzPortalUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    rename_column :zz_portal_users, :user_id, :zz_user_id
  end

  def self.down
    rename_column :zz_portal_users, :zz_user_id, :user_id
  end
end
```

Any idea about where this could come from?

Thanks!

Comment: Not an actual answer, but MySQL does changes by copying the table, performing the changes and the replacing the original table. That's why you see an error during rename. Sadly I can not really determine what the actual root cause of that is. Try to run the db:migrate with `--trace` and maybe have a look into your database log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing id columns in mysql is a bit tricky as all the FK must have the same data type. Can you check that all the FKs you have to that id are int(11).

If that doesn't help, please paste the DDL of the users and any related tables.

Answer (score 3):

From [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table-problems.html)

> If ALTER TABLE dies with the following
>   error, the problem may be that MySQL
>   crashed during an earlier ALTER TABLE
>   operation and there is an old table
>   named A-xxx or B-xxx lying around:
>
> Error on rename of
>   './database/name.frm' to
>   './database/B-xxx.frm' (Errcode: 17)
>   In this case, go to the MySQL data
>   directory and delete all files that
>   have names starting with A- or B-.
>   (You may want to move them elsewhere
>   instead of deleting them.)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by removing the foreign key constraints on the table, then renaming the column, then recreating the foreign key constraint.

To drop the foreign key constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> DROP FOREIGN KEY <constraint_name>;
```

Don't know why MySQL throws this error sometimes... Must say I never have weird problems like this on PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL seems to have some problems renaming columns under foreign-key constraints. We ended up writing

```
class RenameXsYToZ < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    remove_foreign_key :xs, :ys
    rename_column :xs, :y_id, :z_id
    add_foreign_key :xs, :ys, column: :z_id
  end
end
```